# Calling method with return type future is not working in parallel, why?

Tags: scala

I was learning the `Future` monad in scala. I wrote the following code:

```
object MultipleFutures extends App {

  // (a) create three futures
  val aaplFuture = getStockPrice("AAPL")
  val amznFuture = getStockPrice("AMZN")
  val googFuture = getStockPrice("GOOG")

  def sleep(time: Long): Unit = Thread.sleep(time)
  
  Thread.sleep(5000)

  def getStockPrice(stockSymbol: String): Future[Double] = {
    println(s"starting $stockSymbol")
    val r = scala.util.Random
    val randomSleepTime = r.nextInt(3000)
    println(s"For $stockSymbol, sleep time is $randomSleepTime")

    sleep(randomSleepTime)
    fetchData()
  }

  def fetchData() = Future {
      Thread.sleep(Random.nextInt(10000))
      Random.nextDouble()
    }
}
```

I get the result in sequential order:

```
starting AAPL
For AAPL, sleep time is 2925
starting AMZN
For AMZN, sleep time is 336
starting GOOG
For GOOG, sleep time is 1065
```

But when I convert `getStockPrice` method to:

```
def getStockPrice(stockSymbol: String): Future[Double] = Future {
    println(s"starting $stockSymbol")
    val r = scala.util.Random
    val randomSleepTime = r.nextInt(3000)
    println(s"For $stockSymbol, sleep time is $randomSleepTime")

    sleep(randomSleepTime)
    fetchData()
  }.flatten
```

The code started running in parallel.

```
starting AAPL
starting GOOG
starting AMZN
For AAPL, sleep time is 1233
For GOOG, sleep time is 1734
For AMZN, sleep time is 1
```

I don't understand why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first version of `getStockPrice` you are calling `sleep(randomSleepTime)` before creating the `Future` so it is running in the main thread.

In the second version everything in the function is inside the `Future` so it runs in parallel.

To avoid the `Thread.sleep` in the main `App` use

```
val futures = List(aaplFuture, amznFuture, googFuture)

Await.result(Future.sequence(futures), Duration.Inf)
```

Comment: Even though I moved Thread.sleep to the last line I am getting the result in sequential order only. I added thread sleep because the main thread gets completed before the other threads. so we can't get the output if we don't add a delay in the main thread.

Comment: That's not the `sleep` I was referring to; I have clarified my answer.

Comment: That is also one of the ways, but that is not the reason. I replaced sleep with Await.result still it is not running in parallel.
You can try my example on your machine you understand the problem. It is not about using sleep or await I guess.

Comment: In the first version, the code that does the printing is not running in parallel because it isn't inside a `Future`! The only code inside a `Future` is the code in `fetchData` and that doesn't print anything.

Comment: Tim is correct. Put an `.onComplete()` call on every `getStockPrice()` invocation and you'll see that the `Future`s will finish out-of-order because they were running asynchronously.

Comment: Okay you mean only code inside the ```Future```  block run in parallel?

Comment: @TausifSayyad Yes, only the code inside the `Future` runs in parallel with the main thread. `Future` is just a class like any other Scala class, so the fact that a method returns `Future` does not mean that the code in that method runs in parallel with the main thread.

Comment: I was in the impression if the method has a ```Future``` return type that method should run in parallel. @Tim helped a lot.